# Отражается ли как-то на производительность операция возведения в степень? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написал небольшой скрипт, который находит все делители числа.

```
V = 100000000000000

D = []
d = 2
while (d ** 2 <= V):
    if V % d == 0:
        D.append(d)
        d_new = V // d
        if d_new != d:
            D.append(d_new)

    d += 1
```

Начал проверять его скорость, огорчился. Попробовал его как-то оптимизировать, но ничего не получилось. Потом решил поменять операцию возведения в степень на простое умножение.

```
V = 100000000000000

D = []
d = 2
while (d * d <= V):
    if V % d == 0:
        D.append(d)
        d_new = V // d
        if d_new != d:
            D.append(d_new)

    d += 1
```

И как оказалось, скорость кода увеличилась более чем в 2 раза. Проверял через timeit.

1 код: 4.419626179999978

2 код: 2.0235268200000065

Почему так происходит, ведь по идее умножение и возведение в степень (в данном случае) - это одно и то же действие?

Comment: Нет, эти действия выполняются совсем разными функциями. И возведение в степень обычно всегда медленнее, да.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/sgm0dv/why_is_the_power_operator_much_slower_than/

Comment: Кстати, лучше вообще вынести это вычисление за цикл, взяв корень из обеих частей уравнения: `sqr_V = int(V**0.5) ...
while (d <= sqr_V):` Так будет ещё быстрее )

Comment: Благодарю за ответы!

Comment: @ShaRen Вы, наверное, удалили свой вопрос мне, а он в общем-то был по делу. Нет ли ошибок округления, не получится ли, что `int(V**0.5)` даст ответ чуть меньше, чем нужно? Ну, я на всякий случай это проверил сейчас - возводил числа от `1` до `100_000_000` в квадрат и потом брал `int` от корня. Ну и проверял - получилось ли исходное число. Ну в общем на этом диапазоне такой проблемы не обнаружилось.

Comment: Я удалил, потому что вы правы. Если брать округление round(), то допустим при d = 4 и V = 15 цикл бы давал лишний делитель. d * d > 15. d > sqrt(15). Корень 15 это примерно 3.9. Округляя до целого числа получаем 4. d = 4, Откуда получаем лишний делитель 4. При int() такой проблемы не возникает. Еще раз спасибо за ответ!

Comment: P.S. хотя с другой стороны, внутри цикла у меня есть условие V % d == 0, которое в любом случае не пропустит делитель 4, так что round() тоже имеет место быть.

Comment: Ну, я проверял другой случай. Что если скажем корень из 16 даст не ровно 4, а 3.9999998 и потом это округлится до 3 )  Но Питон умный, тут такого вроде бы нет, по крайней мере на тех числах, которые я проверил.

Comment: У меня такая проблема была с возведением числа в 1/3 степень, то бишь кубический корень. Как не танцевал с бубнами, все равно не выходил целочисленный ответ, даже с числами по типу 27, 64 и т.д.

Comment: @ShaRen Да, с кубическим корнем проблема начинается уже от 64, я проверил. С квадратами проще, они вписываются в двоичную модель чисел в памяти компьютера. А со всем остальным уже сложности начинаются. Ну, можно пробовать округлять тогда через `round`. Я проверил - тогда проблем нет.